# ScheduledExecutorService + beans

Tags: java, spring

I have problem with my implementation of ScheduledExecutorService. In run() method of my task I cannot inject bean.

```
public class MyTask implements Runnable{

    @Autowired
    private DataExporter de;

    @Override
    public void run(){

        de.export();
    }

}
```

While running my task object de is null. I know that spring has some task and schedule implementation but is there any way to get this around?

Comment: How are you creating your `MyTask` instance?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating instance of MyTask with a default constructor. Anything that I put in run() will work. Problem is with this injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're creating your instance of `MyTask` like this

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
```

The problem with this is that Spring has no idea that another instance of `MyTask` has been created.  I would suggest creating a prototype bean in the application context:

```
<bean id="myTaskTemplate" class="mypackage.MyTask" scope="prototype" />
```

and then using [lookup method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection).

Add the following abstract method to the bean that is currently creating your `MyTask` instance could

```
protected abstract createMyTask();
```

and add the following to your bean definition

```
<bean id="myTaskCreatingBean" class="...">
  <lookup-method name="createMyTask" bean="myTaskTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

then you can replace

```
MyTask myTask = new MyTask();
```

with

```
MyTask myTask = createMyTask();
```

and the `myTask` bean will have been created by spring and the dependencies correctly autowired.

Comment: Well that did the trick :) after all the problem was not knowing spring well enough by me. Really great thanks for you mate.